# 550W PSU, i5 (3.2ghz), 8gb DDR3 and 12V Rail is at 8V

Tags: memory, cpu, power-supply

I was curious this morning about my temperature and voltage readings so I downloaded Speedfan and CPUID's Hardware Monitor.

I have the following hardware

**CPU :** i5 3.2GHZ

**RAM** : 4 x 2GB DDR3

**GPU :** HD 5770 Hawk

**HDD** : 3 x 7200RPM Drives (SATA2)

**The first question,**
The voltage reading on idle on my 12V rail is sitting at 8V and I've read somewhere that due to windows 7's power management that under idle, the voltage would drop, is that correct?

**The second question,**
My CPU Core is at 42Degrees C, which is fine and i'm happy with it, but my SYSTIN temperature reading is sitting at 100 Degrees, which I cannot believe to be true. Might there be a problem with the earlier DH55C motherboard sensors?

I have not checked what those readings are under load, but I will check tonight. I just want to know whether you folk think that 550W is enough and if these readings are acceptable?

Thanks

Comment: It is very unlikely that your system is working at all if the "12V" is only at 8 volts. Before you do anything else, get a voltage reading you can trust. A LOT of mobo voltage and temp sensors give wrong results. Buy a cheap digital multimeter (e.g. ExTech MN35 or similar... there are cheaper ones, but that's about the cheapest I'd recommend... borrow one from a techie friend if you have to) and measure the voltage at an unused 4-pin "Molex" connector from the PSU. Or "back-probe" the motherboard connectors. The wires with black insulation are ground, yellow for +12, red for +5.

Comment: Oh, and: No, the voltage will not drop due to power management. The system has _no way whatsoever_ to tell the PSU to lower its voltage. Power management causes the system to use less _power_ but that is not done by lowering voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A 33% voltage drop on a rail is too high and indicates that either the PSU is faulty or that the load is too high. And load drops when idle, raising the rail rather than lowering it.
2. That is definitely too high. There may be a fault with the motherboard causing voltage to be converted to heat (and thereby causing the aforementioned rail drop), or it's struggling to compensate for the rail drop caused by the PSU.

There is something severely wrong with your system, and I urge you to take diagnostic and corrective action as soon as possible.

Comment: a 8V voltage in the 12V rail is unlikely to give anything past a POST screen, much less likely a windows interactive session...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you really think that there might not be something just fishy with the sensors? Can you recommend any diagnostics that I can run (software related) that will pin point an issue if there is one?

Comment: Perhaps. I had gone with the assumption that you had tested the rail with a multimeter, and not just gone by what the sensors reported. But sensors this faulty would be a problem with the motherboard regardless. I would not trust software diagnostics at this point, since they would all rely on what the sensors report.

Comment: I will ask the supplier if I can swap out the motherboard then?

Comment: The first thing I would do is check that rail, since if it really *is* that low then a motherboard change won't help. Once you've verified that the rail is fine, then change the motherboard.

Comment: I have another question,
Is my PSU sufficient for this rig?
I will get a Multimeter and check my psu tonight.

Comment: If the rail is fine, then it's likely sufficient. If the rail is low when connected, and fine disconnected, then it is not (but that may be the motherboard's fault).

Comment: Ignacio, I ensured that my PSU has voltage protection in place, under/over voltage protection, so it's most likely the motherboard that is fried, I'm just speculating until I can test myself.

Wouldn't those protection barriers ensure that the power supply isn't supplying too little or too much?

Comment: As an update, I have downloaded the intel utilities and uploaded a screenshot,
http://pieterg.com/Media/51
if you look at the intel desktop utility, the 12v rail is perfect, I have also looked at the reading in the bios hardware monitoring and it's reading 12v correctly too. CPUID and Speedfan is incorrectly reading the 12v rail.

Under load, the 12V rail drops by 3% (to 11.69V), which is fine to me, but it does show that I might need to upgrade my PSU sometime.

Ignacio, do you agree?

Comment: 3% is within tolerances. If you were to add 3 more hard drives then I would consider a larger PSU, but for now it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not the 12V rail being 8V - it is the sensors having problem. You implied in your question that you were able to boot windows 7. In no[1] way would a machine be able to boot with 12V rail at 8V. If anything, the motherboard needs to be changed. Almost any respectable PSU would have undervoltage protection which shutdown the system the moment the voltage runs out of specification.
2. Given (1), I think it is likely that the sensors are having problem. In rare instances of water cooling with no channeled air towards the chipset and voltage regulators it may be possible to heat the 'system' area so badly that you have such reading but I don't think its the case here. :)

Comment: BTW, Use a multimeter...